# Calling server side method from client side javascript

Tags: asp.net

I want to call a method in my code behind from client side javascript.
I found a solution with pagemethods. it is working but the problem is that the server side method should be static. its not working for me because i want to change some of my page class fields. please advise me

Comment: Your page fields only exist in an actual lifeccle of a page(just as all of it's controls), so you need to postback regularly.

Comment: Tim  Please tell me more about it do you have any sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with only Javascript you need to use Ajax you can refer this sample code 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238866/Invoke-Server-Methods-From-Client-Side-Using-JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You either change the page fields you want in Javascript or you do a full postback. If you really want to use a Javascript call, you try something like [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/). It works without refreshing the whole page and it respects the ASP.NET page lifecycle.

Comment: how can i do a full postpack? can i call ____doPostBack ?

Comment: @aliakhbarizadeh yes, that will probably work. you need to post some code for a more detailed answer